# What is the X index register?

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture

I am asking in general. I am trying to understand the purpose of the X index register in any microcontroller in general since I have to create a virtual microcontroller. What is the difference between this register the MAR and the PC? Thanks to all of you who reply.

Comment: Please specify architecture.

Comment: The MAR is an implementation detail.  In architectures with a register named `X`, it's an *architectural* register that holds its value regardless of what else is accessing memory.

Answer (score 3):

The MAR is an implementation detail.  A pipelined CPU might not have MAR per-se, or not a single MAR, especially if it has a multi-ported cache that can read+write in the same cycle.

In architectures with a register named `X`, **`X` is an *architectural* register** that holds its value regardless of what else is accessing memory.

e.g. an absolute non-indexed load would use the MAR to drive the address bus, but CPU would still need to keep the same value for `X`.  Also, MAR has to be as wide as physical addresses in the machine, but `X` is only an 8-bit register in 6502.  (So you can only index 256 bytes from a given base).

The program counter is usually not directly accessible, except by PC-relative addressing modes, or call instructions store the return address somewhere.  And jumps write PC.  But in some ways it's also an implementation detail; a pipelined CPU won't necessarily have a single PC register.  But a scalar in-order pipeline will effectively have a PC in the fetch stage.  (Or a non-pipelined CPU will of course have a single PC.)

**Presumably code-fetch copies PC to MAR** as part of loading the machine code for the next instruction.

---

Architectures with an `X` register include

- [6502 / 6510 index register (8-bit)](https://www.c64-wiki.com/wiki/X_index_register), usable in indirect and absolute indexed addressing modes.
- [Z80 has a 16-bit `IX` register](http://z80-heaven.wikidot.com/the-registers-and-memory#toc11) (index X), composed of 2 8-bit halves.  See https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/6095/why-do-c-to-z80-compilers-produce-poor-code/ for some interesting details about how registers and addressing modes in 6502 and Z80 don't map to the C model of pointers that you can index with an integer.  And not easily supporting stack-relative addressing modes making recursion hard.
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freescale_68HC11 has IX and IY 16-bit index registers.
- AVR (X is the 16-bit concatenation of `r27:r26`): [AVR XYZ Registers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48645379/avr-xyz-registers).  It's not limited to being an index.

8080 has HL, not X.

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply Peter Cordes, would you mind to explain it more simpler ? I have only a basic understanding of microcontrollers and I just want to know what the X index register will do in my virtual microcontroler which only has an accumulator, PC, X index register and zero flag. Thanks.

Comment: @ZalodeMolina: IDK how to answer that without writing a whole textbook or handing you a complete design for a CPU.  Your `X` register can do whatever you decide it can do, e.g. maybe you support an `add X` instruction that lets you add to it as.  Maybe you can only use it as a pointer with a special load instruction, or maybe any instruction with a memory operand can optionally use `[X + something]` as the addressing mode.